# Center a window.open in the screen (not the browser)

Tags: jquery

How to center a window open in the screen? I know there are other solutions but I think they center the new window in relation of the existing window, not the total screen of the computer. So, those solutions only work if the browser is full screen.

My example has that same problem, it only works if the first window is full screen. Is there any solution that works always?

Here is the example to play: http://jsfiddle.net/T7DJr/

(I tried screen.width but it does not work. Is it a jQuery problem?)

Html:

```
<a class="open" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank"> open window </a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){    
    // this only centers in relation to the browser, not the screen:
    var top = $(window).height()/2 - 200;
    var left = $(window).width()/2 - 200;

    $('.open').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.open("","window1",
                    "toolbar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, top="+top+", left="+left+", width=400, height=400");
    }); 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var top = window.screen.height/2 - 200;
var left = window.screen.width/2 - 200;
```

I am not sure about the browser compatibility though.

Comment: Compatibility seems good according to [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t13).

Comment: It works well with Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera. It does not work in ie8. I cannot chech ie9 nor ie10. The problem with ie8 is that it does not recognize window.open

Comment: @Nrc just checked on a XP computer with IE8 (real browser), it worked for me

Comment: Sorry if it is a very basic question but I just want to learn and I cannot find this. When should I use $() or not? I mean like $(window).height()

Comment: @Nrc Going out of topic but $(obj) or jQuery(obj) are wrapped versions of the native javascript objects. While a wrapped object provides jQuery specific properties/methods, you cannot directly access the properties of the native object but have to first get it with the jQuery method .get().